# Переменная вне цикла while

Tags: php

Поломал себе всю голову. Не могу понять, как вынести готовую переменную за пределы цикла "WHILE".

Такой код:

```
 $my_prognoz = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `user`, `user_info` WHERE user.sid = user_info.sid ORDER BY `user_info`.`buy_ok` DESC LIMIT 50");
            while ($my_prognoz_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($my_prognoz)){

$b_ok = $my_prognoz_r['buy_ok'];
$b_bad = $my_prognoz_r['buy_bad'];
$b_tot = $my_prognoz_r['total_prog'];

@$proc = ($b_ok / ($b_ok + $b_bad)) * 100;
$proc_i = round($proc);
?>
    <li class="prognozi_n">
                    <div class="prognoz_info_game"><?=$my_prognoz_r['secname'].' '.$my_prognoz_r['name'];?> - 
                        <span style="color: orange;"><?=$my_prognoz_r['nick'];?></span></div>
                    <div class="prognoz_cash"><span style="color: #c0ff07"><?=$b_ok;?></span> / <span style="color:#e86363 "><?=$b_bad;?></span> [<?=$proc_i;?>%]</div>       
    </li> 
<?}var_dump($proc_i);?>
```

В общем, в цикле я получаю нужное число **$proc_i = 60;**
А когда вызываю его за пределами цикла, оно всегда = 0;
Пытался занести в СЕССИИ, всё равно = ноль

Comment: Мы должны угадать как вы используете переменную вне цикла, или вы все-таки соизволите код показать?

Comment: Здесь нужно учитывать, что `$proc_i` будет присвоено значение только при последней итерации.

Comment: Возможно в последней итерации 0 и должно быть, т.к. каждый раз это число перезаписывается.

Comment: Может проблема в самом условии, ведь если `$b_tot != 0`, то и само значение нужное будет 0.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная "`$proc_i`" - будет доступна после ее объявлении. Т.е переменная видна в  конце первой итерации и во всех остальных итераций цикла, а также всё, что идет ниже цикла. А 0 - это скорее всего результат записи на последней итерации. Ищите проблему тут

```
if($b_tot != 0){
    $proc = ($b_ok / ($b_ok + $b_bad)) * 100;
}else{
    $proc = 0;
}
```

Comment: Это простая формула определения % соотношения. Если даже убрать "условие" результат 0. Суть в том, что результат 60 нужно записать в БД к пользователю по id. Но переменная вне цикла 0. Как реализовать эту запись в БД правильно?

Comment: @WinRate А какому пользователю вы хотите ее записать ? у вас ведь в цикле перебирается много пользователей. И вы там как раз пользователей сортируете по убыванию buy_ok, может у последнего пользователя в выборке он все таки равен нулю, тогда и переменная после цикла равна нулю. Попробуйте в цикле распечатать все значения переменной и посмотрите какое из них _последнее_, вот именно оно и должно быть доступно после цикла